# What is the correct version of transformer image to use with Parcel 2?

Tags: parceljs

I've installed Parcel 2, and it told me I need to use the image transformer plugin to reference an image's file location for this code:

```js
'use strict';

import Phaser from 'phaser';
import imageUrl from "url:/art/image/rogue/Preview.png";  //  <-- here
```

So I `npm install @parcel/transformer-image` and now my `package.json` file looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-nightly.1981",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-nightly.548",
    "phaser": "^3.53.1"
}
```

but now Parcel tells me:

```
@parcel/package-manager: Could not find module "@parcel/transformer-image" satisfying 2.0.0-nightly.2252+dc09f125.

>    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Found this conflicting local requirement.
```

What to do please?

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete the transformer-image line from your package.json and npm and run parcel. It will download the correct version automatically.